# Is $π^3$ greater than $3^π$ or conversely?

Tags: inequality

Using the calculator, we know that

$$3^π > π^3$$

But, without any calculation, how to prove it?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:$$

Compare the logs: it amounts to checking $\;\dfrac{\ln\pi}\pi < \dfrac{\ln 3}3$.

So you should study the *variations* of the function $\;\dfrac{\ln x}x$.

Comment: Your inequality as written is the reverse of what is needed and true.

Comment: Right! I confess I didn't check. Thanks for pointing it. 'Tis corrected now.